# $f(x) = x^{p}(1-x)^{q}$ for all $x\in \left[0,1\right]\;,$ Where $p,q\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$, Then Max. of $f(x)$ at $x=$

Tags: inequality

> The function $f(x) = x^{p}(1-x)^{q}$ for all $x\in \left[0,1\right]\;,$ Where $p,q$ are positive integers,
>
> has maximum value for $x=$

$\bf{Using\; Derivative}$ Let $$f(x) = x^{p}(1-x)^{q}\;,$$ Then $$f'(x) = -x^{p}\cdot q(1-x)^{q-1}+(1-x)^{q}\cdot px^{p-1}$$

So $$\displaystyle f'(x) = x^{p}\cdot (1-x)^{q}\left[-\frac{q}{(1-x)}+\frac{p}{x}\right] = x^{p-1}\cdot (1-x)^{q-1}\left[p-(p+q)x\right].$$

Now for Max. and Min. $$\displaystyle f'(x) = 0\Rightarrow x=0\;\;,x=1\;\;,x=\frac{p}{p+q}$$

Now $$f''(x) = x^{p-1}\cdot (1-x)^{q-1}\left[-(p+q)\right]+(p-(p+q)x)\left[(q-1)x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-2}+p(1-x)^{q-1}x^{p-2}\right]$$

So at $x=0,1\;,$ We get $f''(0)=0.$ So $x=0,1$ is Neither a point of max. or Min.

so at $$\displaystyle x = \frac{p}{p+q}\;,$$ We get $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{p}{p+q}\right)<0$

So $$\displaystyle x= \left(\frac{p}{p+q}\right)$$
is a point of local maximum.

My Question is can we solve it Using Inequality, If yes then plz explain here,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the sum
$$\frac{x}{p}+\cdots +\frac{x}{p}+\frac{1-x}{q}+\cdots+\frac{1-x}{q},$$
where there are $p$ copies of $\frac{x}{p}$ and $q$ copies of $\frac{1-x}{q}$.The sum is $1$, so the arithmetic mean is $\frac{1}{p+q}$.

By AM/GM we have
$$\frac{1}{p+q} \ge \sqrt[p+q]\frac{x^p(1-x)^q}{p^pq^q}$$
with equality when $x/p=(1-x)/q$, that is, when $(p+q)x=p$. Now a little manipulation yields the maximum value of $x^p(1-x)^q$.